# Pros and cons of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package, csproj

In `ASP.NET Core 2.0` there is no need to include individual `package references` in the `.csproj` file. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage contains all the required packages. We can include this metapackage in `.csproj` file as:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
```

What are the main pros and cons of this metapackage in .Net Core applications? (Consider cross platform self contained applications also)

Comment: Yes, it is good practice. The good practice is defined by the framework authors and those created that meta package with the intent to replace the individual imports for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package helps to prevent the hell of dependency versions.

Comment: Major con: You can't downgrade anything in the "metapackage" to match the requirements of some other package. For example, the Azure stack is mostly stalled out on Json.NET 9.0.1, but this dumping-ground package declares minimum dependencies on 10.0.1, which would break the Azure stack.

Comment: good pros-cons are listed at the [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd) as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you create ASP.NET Core 2.0 application running against .NET Core 2.0, you should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (for ASP.NET Core 2.1 and higher, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` is recommended - From ASP.NET Core 3.0 `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` will be removed) as this is the recommended approach and is useful to avoid a long list of dependencies.

When publishing (self-containing) applications, tree-shaking will be applied, this means: the build process will find out which packages inside the metapackage will be used and will strip them from the published folder to keep the size small.

Another reason to use it is the [.NET Core Runtime Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/aspnetcore-2.0#runtime-store). The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package is part of the runtime store so it won't need to be published (as mentioned above) but more importantly, it is precompiled, so startup times improves too.

However

1. You can't use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`) when targeting .NET Framework >= 4.6.1, because it requires `netcoreapp2.0` and `netcoreapp2.1` respectively
2. You can't and shouldn't use it in Portable Class Libraries (PCL) due to the fact that it requires `netcoreapp2.0` and PCLs should be targeting `netstandard2.0`. There are a few exceptions, for example if you depend on a (ASP.NET Core) package which only runs on .NET Core (or you require .NET Core only APIs), since PCLs targeting `netcoreappx.y` can't run on .NET Framework

Comment: it is worth mentioning that this will work for a Portable (FDD) application, whereas neither tree-shaking nor Runtime Store doesn't exist for a Standalone (SCD) app. If I create an empty project (dotnet new web), specify a RuntimeIdentifier (e.g. win10-x64) and publish the app (dotnet publish -r win10-x64) I will see all of the unused DLLs in the output directory. Thus, if someone has plans to deploy his app as SCD, he shouldn't use Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage.