# Why does .Net Core 2.1.1 Generic Host require the huge Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage to work?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to create a .Net Core 2.1.1 console app using the new [generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

It is a really simple program, just a .net core 2.1 console app looking like this:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    internal class Program {
        private async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x => x.SetBasePath("."))
                .RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of installing the huge package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package I figured that I could just install the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting v. 2.1.1`, so my `.csproj` becomes:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This package installs a number of other packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (2.1.1)
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (2.1.1)
- Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical (2.1.1)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions (2.1.1)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (2.1.1)

When I do this I run into trouble because of the extension method `IConfigurationBulider.SetBasePath` (implemented in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions`) cannot be resolved/found by the compiler/build process.

I have tried fully qualifying the extension method, but it is as if the relevant assemblies from the packages are not referenced by the project.

The solution is to add the huge Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage and then it works. But I find it strange that I need to add an AspNetCore package when my app has nothing to do with AspNet Core.

1. Why is it neccessary to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and can it be avoided somehow ?
2. Is it just a temporary issue until the WebHostBuilder has been phased out in favor of the generic host builder ?

Comment: It doesn't. It's not in the dependencies either directly or indirectly. I that package *and* Json configuration in Console applications without any problem. Even in Full Framework projects. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` isn't being added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Why is it neccessary to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and can it be avoided somehow ?

It's not, just convenience and easy to get started with the tutorials. You shouldn't even have to bother, the non-referenced packages will be stripped out anyways when you publish/build the application. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46594364/455493).

> Why is it neccessary to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and can it be avoided somehow ?
>   Is it just a temporary issue until the WebHostBuilder has been phased out in favor of the generic host builder ?

It's not. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions` is part of [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions) package, which you don't reference, hence the error you get